# Como unificar datas com dataframe no Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com a seguinte situação. Tenho uma planilha com as seguintes colunas: nome, sobrenome, datas(de 2011 até 2021)

Segue a tabela para visualizarem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vêem, essas datas estão fora de ordem. Como posso ordená-las sem mudar de posição as colunas nome e sobrenome?

Eu cheguei a executar o código da seguinte maneira:

```
df_json_meses = df_json1.iloc[:, 58:64] # Coluna referente aos meses de ago até dez/2020

df_json_meses2 = df_json1.iloc[:, 52:55] # Coluna que se refere aos meses jan a maio/2021

df_json_meses3 = df_json1.iloc[:, 99] # coluna referente ao mês de jun/2021

df_json_meses4 = df_json1.iloc[:, 55:57] # coluna referente aos meses Jul e Ago/2021

df_json_soma_meses = pd.concat([df_json_meses, df_json_meses2 , df_json_meses3,
```

df_json_meses4], axis=1)

```
df_json_nome = df_json1.iloc[:, :2]


df_json_unico = pd.concat([df_json_nome, df_json_soma_meses], axis=1)
```

Consegui organizar conforme eu queria, só que me atende para esse relatório, agora se eu gerar um novo relátorio, e gerar novas colunas ou menos colunas e a quantidade for menor ou maior que eu setei no código, eu terei que alterar na mão? Se sim, eu não quero isso. Como posso automatizar esse código da melhor forma possível?

Segue o resultado final do relatório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço imensamente quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do seguinte conjunto de dados como exemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Nome': ['João', 'José'],
    'Sobrenome': ['Da Silva', 'Soares'],
    '2011-02': [10, 20],
    '2009-08': [90, 200],
    '2011-12': [1, 5],
    })
print(df)

# output:
#    Nome Sobrenome  2011-02  2009-08  2011-12
# 0  João  Da Silva       10       90        1
# 1  José    Soares       20      200        5
```

Primeiro, reordene todas as colunas com `df.sort_index` (como as datas estão no formato `YYYY-MM`, o algoritmo de ordenamento padrão dá conta de ordená-las em ordem crescente):

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print(df)

# output:
#    2009-08  2011-02  2011-12  Nome Sobrenome
# 0       90       10        1  João  Da Silva
# 1      200       20        5  José    Soares
```

As colunas de datas ficaram ordenadas - só falta trazer as colunas `Nome` e `Sobrenome` para a frente. Podemos fazer isso usando `df.pop` e `df.insert` para retirar a coluna e reinseri-la no começo do dataframe:

```
df.insert(0, "Sobrenome", df.pop('Sobrenome'))
df.insert(0, "Nome", df.pop('Nome'))
print(df)

# output:
#    Nome Sobrenome  2009-08  2011-02  2011-12
# 0  João  Da Silva       90       10        1
# 1  José    Soares      200       20        5
```

Por fim, caso você queira que as colunas de data estejam em ordem decrescente, basta passar o argumento `ascending=False` ao chamar o método `df.sort_index`.

Comment: Bom dia jfaccioni. Obrigado pela ajuda.. Consegui fazer. Não foi preciso eu usar o df.pop e df.insert para retirar e e inserir a coluna no começo. Eu fiz assim:
df.sort_index (axis = 1, inplace = True, ascending = False) e funcionou.

Comment: Uma outra dúvida jfaccioni, desculpe-me incomodá-lo. . Eu quero pegar uma qtde especifica de coluna de 2021-08 até 2020-09.
Eu fiz  meu código dessa forma abaixo:
df_nomes = df.iloc[:, :2]
df_meses = df.iloc((:, 2:14) - 2:14 qtde de colunas de datas  que eu quero. 
df_unico = pd.concat([df_nomes, df_meses], axis = 1)
A minha dúvida é que se, por exemplo, eu gerar um novo relatório, e  aumentar ou diminuir a quantidade de colunas de data, esse código que fiz funcionará sem problemas ou terei que alterar na mão

Comment: Uma outra dúvida jfaccioni, desculpe-me incomodá-lo. . Eu quero pegar uma qtde especifica de coluna de 2021-08 até 2020-09.

Eu fiz  meu código dessa forma abaixo:
df_nomes = df.iloc[:, :2]
df_meses = df.iloc((:, 2:14) - 2:14 qtde de colunas de datas  que eu quero. 
df_unico = pd.concat([df_nomes, df_meses], axis = 1)
df_unico.to_excel('teste.xlsx', index = False)

A minha dúvida é que se, por exemplo, eu gerar um novo relatório em que aumente ou diminua a quantidade de colunas de data, esse código que fiz funcionará sem problemas ou terei que alterar na mão?

Comment: Oi @FabricioRezende, a forma mais simples que consigo pensar é usar o nome das colunas (método `.loc`) ao invés da sua posição (método `.iloc` que você está usando). Por exemplo, parta de `cols = ['2021-08', '2021-07', ... , '2020-10', 2020-09']` e então escreva `df.loc[:, cols]`. Seu problema passa a ser "como criar  uma lista de todos os meses entre uma data final `'2021-08'` e uma data inicial `'2020-09'`". Sugiro procurar pela resposta nesse e em outros sites, ou abrir uma nova pergunta se não encontrar.

Comment: Sobre sua chamada `df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True, ascending=False)`, deve funcionar sim, porque o `ascending=False` ordena as colunas em ordem reversa a que demonstrei na minha resposta. Apenas note que isso faz com que a coluna `'Sobrenome'` apareça antes de `'Nome'`, mas se isso não for um problema para você, então não precisa mesmo usar `df.pop` e `df.insert`.

Comment: Gratidão @jfaccioni. Consegui fazer funcionar. Dei um sort.index no meu dataframe df_meses. Ficou da forma que eu preciso. Vlw mesmo... Abraços.